# Django REST Framework Model Serializer is not showing all fields for POST method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make custom `create()`method to save my user profile when a User is created, the `serializer` works perfect for the GET method, but for POST it only shows one field instead of all fields.

I specified the `fields = '__all__'` property, but still don't work

GET:

[image: GET]

JSON Response:

```
[
  {
    "job_title": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Desarrollador"
    },
    "birthdate": "2019-11-06",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administrador",
        "description": "Administrador del sistema",
        "key": "ADMIN"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

POST:

[image: POST]

Expected JSON:

```
[
  {
    "birthdate": "2019-11-06",
  }
]
```

Serializers:

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = '__all__'
            depth = 1

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=False, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('user_profile')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

views.py

```py
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    profile = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=UserProfile.objects.all())
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

models.py

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    job_title = models.ForeignKey(JobTitle, related_name='job_title', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

    def createProfile(sender, **kwargs):
         if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.created(user=kwargs['instance'])

         post_save.connect(createProfile, sender=User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I need that POST method also requires the full JSON, the same as the GET JSON response, in order to complete the create method. Need this for POST method:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "user_profile": {
            "job_title": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Desarrollador"
            },
            "birthdate": "2019-11-06",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Administrador",
                    "description": "Administrador del sistema",
                    "key": "ADMIN"
                }
            ]
        },
        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$150000$0XdmQpeiPtVl$rQh2MEYV+IO5Y4gm2o1md2cVzgn/mL95r6m1TvRmG3g=",
        "last_login": "2019-11-06T00:34:25-06:00",
        "is_superuser": true,
        "username": "aruiz",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "correo@correo.com",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2019-11-05T11:37:49-06:00",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": []
    }
```

Comment: You're returning user and NOT user profile in the create() method.

Comment: @Bober In the UserSerializer I'm returning the created user, or which part do you mean?

Comment: Maybe the code example has wrong indentation, but shouldn't `fields = '__all__'` and `depth = 1` be defined in `Meta` class instead of `UserProfileSerializer`?

Comment: The generic view returns the object returned from serializer's create() method as response's body. You're creating a new UserProfile but it's not in the response because create() returns only user.